# How to create a constraint that allows 2 options using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Could anyone help saying how I could create a constraint that allows 2 options using SQL Server?

For exapmle, I want it to be possible to add new candidates only if they have an intermediate or advanced knowledge in SQL.

So, I coded like below, but it doesn’t work.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Candidates
( 
    Name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    BirthDate DATE NOT NULL,
    SQLlevel VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
        CHECK (SQLlevel = 'Intermediate' OR 'Advanced') 
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *it doesn't work* isn't very helpful - can you **show us** how you're trying to insert a new candidate, and what possible error you get from that??¨

Comment: Your `CHECK` constraint needs to be: `CHECK (SQLlevel = 'Intermediate' OR SQLLevel = 'Advanced')`

Comment: @marc_s Not sure your first comment helps. Sure, it might have the rules at its back, but 1) it is a problem anyone with experience would notice in a second. You probably did yourself judging from your second comment. 2) The first sentence of OP, along with sample code in the end, defines a question well enough independently of the produced error. This question is not missing anything.

Comment: Guys, thank you soo much for your attention, some people clarify my doubt below, I'm new here and also new in programing, I appreciate so much your collaboration. Thanks a lot, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain why what you had didn't work it's because of your boolean expression:

```sql
SQLlevel = 'Intermediate' OR 'Advanced'
```

Your expression after the `OR` isn't a boolean expression, it's just a literal. You have to define the comparison operator each time. If you wanted to use a `OR` you would need to do the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Candidates (Name varchar(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                         BirthDate date NOT NULL,
                         SQLlevel varchar(100) NOT NULL CHECK (SQLlevel = 'Intermediate' OR SQLlevel = 'Advanced'));
```

Comment: Umm, did you forget to change the check to the correct form?

Comment: Derp, @GeorgeMenoutis , but have failed at pressed `Ctrl`+`C` again from the IDE>

Comment: Thank you soo much for your attention, and answer, you helped me a lot.
I'm new here and also new in programing, I appreciate so much your collaboration. Thanks a lot, really.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in`:

```
CREATE TABLE Candidates (
    Name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    BirthDate DATE NOT NULL,
    SQLlevel VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    CHECK (SQLlevel IN ('Intermediate', 'Advanced'))
)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your attention, and answer, you helped me a lot.
I'm new here and also new in programing, I appreciate so much your collaboration. Thanks a lot, really.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the word `CONSTRAINT` and a name

```
CREATE TABLE Candidates
( 
    Name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    BirthDate DATE NOT NULL,
    SQLlevel VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    constraint chck_candidates_levels
        CHECK (SQLlevel in('Intermediate', 'Advanced'))
);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your attention, and answer, you helped me a lot.
I'm new here and also new in programing, I appreciate so much your collaboration. Thanks a lot, really.